# How to force set layout params for custom view

Tags: android

here is my code, I hope make view like html5 `<hr/>`

```
public class Hr extends View {

    public Hr(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ii();
    }

    public Hr(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ii();
    }

    void ii() {
        setBackgroundColor(col(this, R.color.gray));
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        lp.topMargin = 5;
        lp.bottomMargin = 5;
        setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```

but when i test it:

```
<ro.adr.Hr android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

the result is gray block, why `lp` doesn't work?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is with the order of things that happen when a `View` is inflated from layout `xml`.

If you go through the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java) of the [`LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) class, you'll see that the order is:

1. Parsing `xml` as `attrs` (a particular part of the `xml` related to specific `ViewGroup` child)
2. Creating `View`
3. Setting `LayoutParams` created based on the previously obtained `attrs`

That means that the `LayoutParams` you create inside your constructor (`lp`) are being overwritten by the `LayoutParams` from the `xml` (in the `3.` step).

What you can do to fix that is to move your `ii()` call to the `onAttachedToWindow()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    ii();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For custom views, you can override the onMeasure(), something like:

```
 @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(500,500);
    }
```

and
`setMeasuredDimension()`
can be used to set the desired dimensions.